# Как передать аргумент из импортированного модуля?

Tags: python

Я импортирую модуль testmodule, который содержит класс

```
class Employee():

def __init__(self, fname, lname, moneyperyear):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.moneyperyear = moneyperyear

def give_raise(self, increase='5000'):
    self.moneyperyear += increase
```

И в новой программе, в которую я импортировал этот класс, я хочу присвоить переменной аргумент moneyperyear для дальнейшей проверки. Как это сделать?

Comment: Импортируете, создаёте экземпляр класса, обращаетесь к необходимым полям через оператор `.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Employee():

    def __init__(self, fname='', lname='', moneyperyear=0):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.moneyperyear = moneyperyear

    def give_raise(self, increase=5000):   # надо int     ? '5000'
        self.moneyperyear += increase
        print(self.moneyperyear)


employe = Employee(moneyperyear=11)
employe.give_raise()
```

---

```
5011
```

---

**Update**

**main.py**

```
from testmodule import  Employee

employe = Employee(moneyperyear=11)
employe.give_raise()
```

**testmodule.py**

```
class Employee():

    def __init__(self, fname='', lname='', moneyperyear=0):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.moneyperyear = moneyperyear

    def give_raise(self, increase=5000):   # надо int     ? '5000'
        self.moneyperyear += increase
        print(self.moneyperyear)
```